# How to view Contacts via new Messages?

Tags: messages

With iChat, i used to be able to view my contacts and know, for example, who is online.

Using `Messages`how can i get a list of those google contacts, currently online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a little trouble with this as well. To view the familiar iChat style list of online "Buddies" (a.k.a Contacts) in the Messages app, you can go to "Window" in the menu bar and click on "Buddies."

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>**⌘**</kbd>+<kbd>**1**</kbd>.